# In an instance of a class, can you use a value returned from a one method, as a parameter for calling another method

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, instance

```
class A:
   def __init__(self, matrix=[]):
       self.matrix = matrix

   def dimension(self):
       return len(self.matrix), len(self.matrix[0])

   def reduce_matrix(self, i, j):
       temp = self.matrix[:i-1] + self.matrix[i:]
       M = A([row[:j-1] + row[j:] for row in temp])
       return M

   def determinant(self):
       (nrows, ncols) = self.dimension()
       if nrows != ncols:
           return ("Cannot find determinant of non-square matrix.")
       elif nrows == 1:
           return self.matrix[0][0]
       else:
           M = A(sum([ ((-1)**j) * self.matrix[0][j] * self.reduce_matrix(1, 
                   j+1).determinant() for j in range(ncols) ]))
           return M
```

Hello, I just started OOP so I have a question regarding using the returned value of a method in place of the "instance name" that is passed as "self" for some other method.

I included the rest of the code that just makes the calculations for a matrix problem, but I'm only focusing on the "**self.reduce_matrix(1, j+1)).determinant()"** bit of it. I need to take a matrix (which is a list of lists ex. [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] ), and perform the "reduce_matrix" method 1 time per column in the matrix, and each time, the "determinant(self)" method passes in the value returned from the other method. When I run it, it says that "list object has no attribute "determinant"" because I can't pass in "self" to the determinant method like I usually do --> "self.determinant(self)"

Any suggestions will be very appreciated

Comment: I'm really confused by this question. Did you edit the code in it to take the error out? That's not how questions are supposed to work on this site. By all means fix the code on your own system, but don't change the question to get rid of the error you were asking for help about!

Comment: Sorry, I just tweaked a part of the code that wasn't the part I had trouble with, because the person that answered below pointed out that I wrote the one part wrong so I thought it would be more clear for people if I corrected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `reduce_matrix`:

- create `M` as `M = A([row[:j-1] + row[j:] for row in temp])`
- do not return `M.matrix` but `M` itself.

That said, [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) is there for all kind of matrix operations and more.

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't even know about libraries until you just mentioned one and I looked it up, that made things so much easier.